# Automatically enabling spell checking in vimrc

Tags: vim

How can I enable spell checking to be automatically enabled in the .vimrc file? Perhaps there's a way to define a quick shortcut that would toggle it instead.

Better yet, is possible to enable it for certain file extensions only?

Comment: what do you do to enable it now?

Comment: @sehe :setlocal spell spelllang=en_us

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be able to just put `set spell` in your .vimrc file.

Answer (score 22):

For only certain file extensions, you can use the [autocommands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand) in Vim:

```
au BufRead *.txt setlocal spell
```

Answer (score 6):

To quickly toggle spelling on and off, you can use the following mapping:

`nmap <silent> <leader>s :set spell!<CR>`

Spell check tends to slow down the loading of big files.

Comment: How is it toggled off afterwards?

Comment: @dustin: by the same combination <leader>s. When you add '!' at the end of command, it means you want to toggle it, i.e set it to false when it is currently true, and set it to true when it is currently false.

Comment: More details: [http://vimcasts.org/episodes/spell-checking/](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/spell-checking/)

Answer (score 2):

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

append a line:

```
setglobal spell spelllang=en_us
```

(or similar)

```
:w|source %
```

Profit

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Xavier T.'s answer but will spell-check the local buffer only, specify the language or region, and set the toggle to F5. Put the following in `~/.vimrc`

```
:map <F5> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR>
```

You can also use `en_au`, `en_ca`, `en_gb`, etc.